# How to run swift code after terminate app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to run ios application code unlimited/ long time while the user terminate my app from background? Please help me.

I have searched a lot but did not find any proper solution.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: You can monitor the traffic from the phone with Charles Proxy after the app is terminated if you need to check on request/response from some backend calls

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible.

There are a bunch of services that you can run in the background such as Location Services BUT even for that you need to configure your app and have the CONSENT of the END USER to continue to monitor his/her location. Even if the user consents, he has a bunch of options like monitor my location while using the app or always or never.

All these options are something that user can change in the "Settings" section of the iOS device.

Even if you try to run your app or any of the services background without the consent of the End user, Apple will definitely reject your app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes i used location services in background but it is stop when user swipe/killed/close  the app from background

Comment: Doesn't seems to me there is some other solution. That is how the Apple security policy works. The only thing is when the user selects to let you monitor his/her location "Always" something you cannot force.